# Renouncing Moroccan citizenship

Tags: citizenship

What can a Moroccan do to renounce their Moroccan citizenship? I have no ties or any affiliations with Morocco nor have I ever been happy to be one, and I despise it. I wasn't even born there in the first place, and I have nothing there, no house, relatives willing to harm me, no property, nothing whatsoever.

I've read somewhere that it's possible and elsewhere it's impossible, but I also heard that ultra rich people have the chance to delete their own records from there and delete their identity or ties completely with the country, hence it's a privilege and it being a privilege says everything about the country

Internationally and with human rights conventions and related-stuff, how can I make renouncement of the above mentioned citizenship?

I can tear off or burn my old passport and my "carte nationale", but I do not know if it's enough

Comment: Do you have dual citizenship? I think this might be a better question for [Expats.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is your other citizenship? Is that other citizenship revocable?

Comment: @Ron Beyer it is not related

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate Monica I have a EU citizenship

Comment: @RonBeyer: Due to the sticky nature of Moroccan citizenship, many Europeans have dual citizenship from birth. They're not expats in any sense of the word.

Comment: @abdul: What, ultimately, are you trying to achieve? A sense of self-satisfaction or symbolic action? Removal/reduction of Moroccan jurisdiction of yourself? Citizenship is based upon recognition, so under a certain course of action Morocco might still claim you as one of their citizens, but another country may refuse to recognize it.

Comment: Just for some context, I would note that some countries do not allow loss of nationality.  I do not know whether Morocco is such a country.  Article 15 of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights declares a right to change one's nationality, which implies a right to renounce or relinquish one's nationality, but it doesn't generally have the force of law.  I do not know the status of the UDHR in Morocco.  Very few countries if any would consider that the destruction of a passport or other evidence of nationality leads to the loss of that nationality.

Comment: @sharur I'm not trying to achieve anything in order to brag myself out, I'm just asking about a thing that I do not like and didn't depend on me in the first place. I would maybe like to make something so offensive against Morocco that I'd be relinquished my citizenship as a punishment (but that's my purpose), but I'm not meaning to show anything to the world, I just feel Moroccan citizenship as a burden and a useless weightful status.

Comment: How exactly does the possession of Moroccan citizenship affect you? Why can't you simply forget about it?

Comment: For those wondering if this even matters: Yes, it does. For instance, in the Netherlands it's possible to lose the Dutch nationality after being convicted of a crime, but only if this does not leave one stateless. This has resulted in a number of criminals being deported to Morocco, despite having been born and raised in the Netherlands.

Comment: Being deported in Morocco is the worst thing that can happen to a dual national. Some years ago in Italy, a 16-year old guy who was born and grew up in Italy with Moroccan lineage did not acquire citizenship yet, because the law states that anyone born in Italy from immigrants must wait till the 18th birthday and have at least 10 years of residence, was deported to Morocco and because he didn't know the language nor did he know how to conduct himself, he killed himself upon arrival.

Comment: @Greendake it could happen that I may get accused of some crime and hence for that particular crime I'm going to have my citizenship revoked, and eventually deportation, and on the conditions I mentioned in the last comment, well, it would be hell for me, I can just die there.

Comment: @Greendake, other possible scenario, let's suppose I travel to Morocco with my EU passport and Moroccan "carte nationale" (premise, dual citizenship is not illegal), and let's suppose that upon return, at immigration, I show always my EU passport and my "carte nationale". It can happen that an immigration officer can say "so you have a EU passport uh...you know what? You're not leaving from here, yallah, I don't like your face", what am I going to do? Can I defend my self then? No. Can I get consular help from Italy? No, because I'm a Moroccan in Morocco, hence internal affairs.

Comment: Once one gets deported in Morocco, it's the end for them. Many Moroccan soccer team players use their European passports and have not renounced their European citizenships for loyalty reasons, does that tell you something?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have Moroccan citizenship by filiation. The relevant law seems to be [Dahir n° 1-58-250 du 21 safar 1378 (6 septembre 1958) portant la Code de la nationalité marocaine](https://www.refworld.org/topic,50ffbce524d,50ffbce525c,3ae6b5778,0,,,MAR.html). It is not clear what the actual procedure is. Chapter 4 covers renunciation and involuntary loss (for e.g. insulting the King). Art. 19 includes some possible cases: case 1, an adult Moroccan who has voluntarily acquired a foreign nationality abroad and is authorized by decree to renounce Moroccan nationality. Article 25 indicates that petition the Minister of Justice, who will determine whether the legal conditions are met, and "to assess whether the favor sought is justified from the national point of view".

However, if you were born in the US (or any other *jus soli* jurisdiction)  to Moroccan parents, you did not acquire that citizenship voluntarily, in which case if the Minister of Justice is a stickler for detail, you do not satisfy the requirements for renunciation of citizenship.

Comment: I acquirer Italian citizenship at my 18th birthday. The thing is that anyone born in Italy from immigrants can acquire citizenship at 18th birthday without applying or submitting any dossier whatsoever, and this act is voluntary, but the thing is that if the interested individual waits more than 6 months after turning 18, then he has to apply like everyone else (minimum wage, amount of years of paid taxes, working years and so forth)

Comment: @abdul You should first attempt to renounce that citizenship based on accepting another citizenship which (theoretically) is allowed. And do so **calmly** and  **politly**.